# ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels when LabelEncoding MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So currently I have an 18 x 80 pandas Dataframe which are grouped under two labels "TEAM ONE" and "TEAM TWO". All the categorical columns are in an array. Because the data is not numerical (they contain strings), I'd need to encode them using the LabelEncoder.

```
categoricals = ['TRAITS', 'UNIT_1', 'UNIT_2', 'UNIT_3', 'AUGMENT_1', 'AUGMENT_2', 'AUGMENT_3']
# Creating a label encoder dictionary for each categorical column
le = {col: LabelEncoder() for col in categoricals}

# example iteration
# d = train_data[('TEAM ONE', 'TRAITS')] = le['TRAITS'].fit_transform(train_data[('TEAM ONE', 'TRAITS')].astype(str))

for col in train_data.columns.levels[0]:
    for sub_col in train_data.columns.levels[1]:
        if sub_col in le:
            train_data[(col, sub_col)] = le[sub_col].fit_transform(train_data[(col, sub_col)].astype(str))
            test_data[(col, sub_col)] = le[sub_col].transform(test_data[(col, sub_col)].astype(str))
```

the train_data line in the `if` statement passes just fine, but when it gets to test_data, it breaks giving the ValueError y contains previously unseen labels. Unlike OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder doesn't have the `handle_unknown` parameter. There's also `try/except ValueError` but this seems impractical. Is there possibly a way the test_data has knowledge of these values before trying to transform?

Comment: One issue I see is that the [labelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is supposed to be used for the response variable `y`. But here you're using it for the features `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code, it is fitting the encoder to the training dataset and not seeing the test dataset, which then causes the issue of `unseen lable`.

The fix in your case would be to make sure your encoder has seen all the data both `training` and `testing` datasets.

Try running `fit_transform` of the encoder on the whole data.